# Duplicated code dependency injection JavaEE

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I've got interface 'FileFactory' with 'produce' method.
This interface is implemented by two classes: 'SingleFileFactory' and 'MultipleFileFactory'.
Both of these classes have the same code structure but returning different injected object.
IntelliJ prints infirmation, that code in both classes is duplicated.
 I can't paste original code, so it's an example

Example:

```
public class SingleFileFactory {

@Inject
private FiirstSingleFile firstSingleFile;

@Inject
private SecondSingleFile secondSingleFile;

public File produce() {
if(something)
return firstSingleFile;
else
return secondSingleFile;
}
}
```

Class 'MultipleFileFactory' has the same logical but different injected objects.

I wanted to separate code into multiple classes, because in my opinion each can return specific object in the result.

Do you know how to avoid such as duplication - should I stretch it and pack into one class with a lot of injects and if expressions?
Maybe you have better solution for this problem.

Comment: It's just a tool, trying to help you identify diplications. You'e the smart human being in control. If you think this duplication is a good thing, just ignore the message from the dumb tool.

Comment: Consider extracting the common logic into an abstract base class (`AbstractFileFactory`).